# Is there a way to make Google Assistant work with React Native App

Tags: react-native, dialogflow-es, google-assistant-sdk, assistant

As the title suggests, I made a assistant agent in DialogFlow but now I need my assistant to be called when I press a button inside the app, I checked out react-native-dialogflow but it is not supported anymore and is giving me errors in my app.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Dialogflow client (I'd recommend to use Node.js):

https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/quick/api?hl=es-419#detect-intent-text-nodejs

Then, You will be able to connect the app to the Dialogflow client through REST (for example using a POST as a verb) to send and receive messages from the assistant

It's needed to develop a chat component in your app to show the conversation. After that, you could integrate the assistant where you want easily

The architecture for your app will be:
**App <-> Dialogflow client <-> Dialogflow**

For Google assistant will be:
**Google Assistant <-> Dialogflow**

Your assistant will be deployed in two different channels but both will use same Dialogflow agent

Comment: Thanks. I dont want my app to have its own Google Assistant, so I dont need chat a component. I want it to send a command like "Ask my Smart Home Assistant to turn on light" which will be handled by my Pixel's inbuilt Google Assistant. Or if thats not possible then at least just trigger my phone's google assistant when I press a button in the app.

Comment: @Overdrive141 did you manage to solve it? I want to do the same thing :)

Answer (score 0):

Here, two actions are required.

1. Enable deep links:
   This is for deep linking an external link to start an application. Here is the link for reference: https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking
2. Enable android shortcut
   To use a Google Voice Assistant shortcut to carry out a specific task. visit https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/shortcuts for more details.

A thorough instruction is available here:
https://sonique6784.medium.com/integrating-your-android-app-with-google-assistant-cb97f54c5fc8